# C++ QQuickItem: How to trigger a function on item size change

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a QQuickItem in C++ which is instantiated in a QML application. I want to trigger a custom function on the c++ side if the width property of my QQuickItem changes.

In QML I would do onWidthChanged: { my code}. How can I do this on the c++ side?

Comment: I edited the title because it was a bit confusing by mixing windows and items, when it seems that you're only interested in size changes of items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to respond to size changes in a custom `QQuickItem`, reimplement the [`geometryChanged()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#geometryChanged) function. This has the benefit of not creating extra [signal-slot connections](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject-connection.html) for each item, as would be necessary if you were to connect to the `widthChanged()`/`heightChanged()` signals.

[Here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/quicktemplates2/qquickcontrol.cpp?h=5.11.0#n1599)'s an example of it being reimplemented in Qt Quick Controls 2.

Answer (score 1):

[`width`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#width-prop) is `qproperty` that has the `widthChanged` signal, so you can connect that signal to some slot.

```
class FooItem : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FooItem(QQuickItem *parent=Q_NULLPTR): QQuickItem(parent){
        connect(this, &FooItem::widthChanged, this, &FooItem::onWidthChanged);
    }
    Q_SLOT void onWidthChanged(){
        qDebug()<<width();
    }
};
```

Similarly, the other properties such as [`height`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#height-prop), [`x`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#x-prop), [`y`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#y-prop), [`z`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#z-prop).