# Is it possible to get QQuickItem layout change event?

Tags: qt, events, qml, signals, qquickitem

Is it is possible QQuickItem layout change?

Is there a way to trigger function when layout/size ( x, y, width or hight) is changed?

There is way to connect on every propery signal change but this is not right way.

Already tried windowChanged signal but it doesn't work for this.

What I am trying to do is to call extrenal java function providing x(GLOBAL),y(GLOBAL),width,height every time my QQuickItem layout/size (any of these) change.

edit:
I need to know the geometry after rendering is done. So I cannot connect to every property by itself.

Comment: Take a look at this, maybe it helps [is-there-a-window-resize-event-signal](https://godotengine.org/qa/14009/is-there-a-window-resize-event-signal) it may help this function : `void QQuickItem::windowChanged(QQuickWindow *window)` [#windowChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#windowChanged) i never used it, so i cannot tell what behaviour have but from what i searched it's ok, signal is sent  when item is resized.

Comment: @Skywrath Thanks, tried that one, but i never get that signal.

Comment: Hmm, then try to put QQuickItem into a container and check resize at parent? Or another bad idea: make a function that takes width and height and call it every time you make an action (press a button or something that you know that it will change the size ), if your function return different result then the original one, do what you wanted to do when resize was triggered. xD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ QQuickItem: How to trigger a function on item size change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49667771/c-qquickitem-how-to-trigger-a-function-on-item-size-change)

Comment: are you subclassing `QQuickItem` yourself?

Comment: I think it would be worth differentiating between signals and functions in your question. It seems that you don't want to connect to signals, so it's probably worth editing your question to say "function" instead.

Comment: The thing is, I need to call external java function providing x,y,width,height every time my QQuickItem layout/size changes.

Comment: @Mitch i need to know the geometry after rendering is done. So I cannot connect to every property by itself.

Comment: 1. I don't understand why you can't connect to the changed signals independently. 2. Why do you need the geometry after the Item has been rendered? Do you expect the geometry to change in between the signal and the rendering? By what cause? When you have tried windowChanged... Is there something about a window that we should know about, to help you?

Comment: @skywrath: why should the window change if an Item is resized?

Comment: @derM i had something else in mind, but he edited the post so my solution is useless now xD

Comment: @Skywarth: The question is very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Connect each property to a single function which checks the "geometry"  as compared to some saved variable, and if something doesnt match up, emit a new signal

```
Item {
   id: myItem
   onXChanged: { myItem.checkGeometry() }
   onYChanged: { myItem.checkGeometry() }
   onWidthChanged: { myItem.checkGeometry() }
   /* etc etc */

   signal: geometryChanged(var _x, var _y, var _width, var _height)

   property var  oldGeometry: [ myItem.x, myItem.y, myItem.width, myItem.height]
   function checkGeometry() { 
     var geometryToCheck = [mapToGlobal(myItem.x), mapToGlobal(myItem.y), myItem.width, myItem.height];
     for (var i=0; i<oldGeometry.length; i++) {
          if (oldGeometry[i] !== geometryToCheck[i]) {
               myItem.geometryChanged(mapToGlobal(myItem.x), mapToGlobal(myItem.y), myItem.width, myItem.height);
               myItem.oldGeometry = geometryToCheck;
               break;
          }
     }
   }
```

Comment: This is something i tried to avoid. But it looks like this is only solution.